# Powershell - Set-MaiboxCalendarFolder

Tags: powershell

A little rusty on my PowerShell so thought I would seek help from Stack. Importing a CSV with usernames (column User) and trying to set their mailbox calendars

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline

$users = import-csv c:\document.csv
foreach($user in $users)
{
    Set-MailboxCalendarFolder $($user.user)":\Calendar" -PublishEnabled $true
}
```

Unfortunately, I am receiving the following error

```
Set-MailboxCalendarFolder : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ':\Calendar'.
At line:6 char:5
+     Set-MailboxCalendarFolder $($user.user)":\Calendar" -PublishEnabl ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-MailboxCalendarFolder], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Set-MailboxCalendarFolder
```

Its not liking something in my code but cant seem to figure it out. Can someone guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Move the double quote before the user variable `”$($user.user):\Calendar"`